# Keeping origin at geometry after changes to the mesh

Tags: origin

I am coming from Sketchup and new to Blender. Probably there is a good reason for it, but for me it is annoying that every time I modify a mesh, the origin moves (or rather stays at its original place) and doesn't adapt to the new mesh.

Is there a way to automatically move the origin to the center every time the mesh is modified? (like a checkbox etc), or maybe an add-on?

I know I can achieve this through the menus but I don't want to do it every time.

Comment: The origin will stay at its position, it's how it works, I'm not sure how you want it to act, for example you would want it to stick to a particular vertex?

Comment: Not a particular vertex but to the center of the mesh. After I modify a mesh; if I rotate, scale it etc. it`s origin isn`t at the center anymore so the result is not the desired one. Every time  I need to move the origin to the center manually. I want the origin to move the center of the new geometry automatically (not manually).

Comment: I haven't heard any way to keep the origin at the center of the mesh, you need to do it afterwards, but maybe there's a python script that could do it

Comment: Hello ! Can you explain the exact reason why this behaviour is bothersome ? We may help you find another solution which is built in Blender

Comment: Right-click the button in the menu that you use and create a shortcut for it

Comment: @Gorgious for instance I make a door from a cube by editing the mesh in edit mode; when I try to rotate this door to place on a perpendicular wall I want it to rotate around itself and that is obviously only possible if the origin is in the center. Btw I know probably I am looking at it from a completely different methodology; i.e. through Sketchup`s and I have to get used to Blender, but I just thought maybe there was an option

Comment: @pysonic the problem is I forget it, and I always have to go back several steps. Otherwise `set origin` option is already in the context menu

Comment: @joethelion If you need it to happen automagically everytime you exit edit mode I do not know of any addon to do that. Blender is very heavy on it's shortcuts, learning them will make your workflow MUCH more efficient. Especially if you create your own set.

Comment: Another way is by using the `q` button Quick Favorites menu. Then all you need to do is remember the `q` button and you can put your several most used tools there

Comment: Yes, that is better than nothing, thanks! I want to mark as best reply, but not sure if my 1 point reputation will let that :D